# How can I fix the error 'webpack_require__.g.addEventListener is not a function' in Tesseract.js with Electron and webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, tesseract.js

I'm trying to build an Electron/Webpack app that uses Tesseract.js for OCR, but when I call `Tesseract.createWorker`, I get this error message:

```
A JavaScript error occured in the main process.
Uncaught Exception: TypeError: __webpack_require__.g.addEventListener is not a function...
```

This is the code that I'm trying to use to create the Tesseract worker (in the main thread):

```js
const worker = await Tesseract.createWorker({
    workerPath: new URL('../node_modules/tesseract.js/dist/worker.min.js', import.meta.url),
    logger: m => console.log(m)
});
```

This project is based on the `webpack-typescript` Electron Forge quickstart.

I have tried changing the URL to workerPath to point directly to the tesseract.js worker script with an absolute path, but I got the same error.